# How to load ASP function via jQuery hosted in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

I'm upgrading a classic ASP application. This app has a few old unmanaged DLL calls and some complicated logic inside the asp page/function.

Is it possible for me to put the .asp file into the ASP.NET MVC app and then load the result using `$.get`?

I try putting the .asp file straight into the Scripts or Models folder but I couldn't load the .asp file when I try to run it straight from the server:

```
This type of page is not served.
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served 
because it has been explicitly forbidden.  
The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL  
below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this funcationality?

Comment: Which windows server version are you running?  It's an IIS setting for ASP most likely, but the answer differs depending on which edition you're running (they moved all the control panels around).

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an ignoreroute so that the original processing on the file exists, though I don't know if that will help with ASP extension, that's what I'm not sure of.  But it's worth a shot, and if you have these files in the same folder, that helps with setting up the ignore route.  More info at:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505203%28VS.100%29.aspx
- http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/09/three-common-aspnet-mvc-url-routing-issues/
- http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/ignoreroute-in-asp-net-routing-is-order-dependent/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your trying to run it by launching the site from Visual Studio to test. This wont work as VS cannot serve Classic ASP pages. You have to hook it up to IIS on your machine to make it work. Or you don't have the ability to run server scripts configured correctly in IIS if it is attached to IIS.